# Prevent duplicates between parent divs

Tags: jquery, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to figure this out and am probably just overlooking the simple. The parent1 div is being dynamically populated from a search. The child divs can be appended between the 2 parent divs. I have the following:

```
<div id="parent1">
    <div class="child1">some data</div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
    <div class="child2">some data</div>
    <div class="child2">more data</div>
    <div class="child2">even more data</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#parent1 .child1').live('click', function() {
    if($('#parent2 .child2 > "' + $(this) + '").length) {
        alert("exists!");
    }
    else
    { // not exist
        $(this).remove().appendTo('#parent2');
    }
});
</script>
```

I am trying to prevent duplicates being appended from parent1 to parent2 using a jquery click event function. I have tried many things only to have it always fail. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Show us your click() function

Comment: share the fiddle if you can...

Comment: I hope the text is distinct. if so, compare with the text.

Comment: by duplicate u meant element having same class or having same text inside or what...just duplicate does not make sense here.....

Comment: same text inside not class. Should I go about it a different way and keep the class the same in both parents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend using `.on()` over `.live()`.

The strategy I have is pretty simple: when a click event is triggered in a child div in #parent1, iterate through and search all content in child divs in #parent2. Increment a variable should a match be found, and don't do anything if nothing is found.

After the search is complete, evaluate the count. If the count is less than 1 (i.e. no match), then copy the text in the clicked div in #parent1 and append to #parent2.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#parent1 > div', function() {
        var childcontent = $(this).text(),    // Get content in clicked div
            count = 0;                        // Start counter

        // Search through each child in #parent2
        $('#parent2 > div').each(function() {
            var target = $(this).text();
            if(target.search(new RegExp(childcontent, "i")) < 0) {
                // No match found in #parent2
                // Do nothing
            } else {
                // Match is found in #parent2
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Evaluate count, make decision to append
        if(count < 1) {
            $(this).remove().clone().appendTo('#parent2');   
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/mr2nP/

Comment: Terry,Thanks! Adapted to my complete function and works great!

Answer (score 0):

Its  best practice to  remove the duplicate `records` coming in search instead of removing duplicate `DOM` `elements`.

If you want to `remove` the divs  compare the text inside the `DIV` elements and `remove` them.